# J2V8 for Android, context methods

Tags: android, j2v8

I'm using J2V8 port for Android (https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8).

Is it possible to enable context methods (setInterval, setTimeout, ..)?

```
V8 runtime = V8.createV8Runtime("global");
runtime.executeIntegerScript("setInterval(function() { 
console.log(\"Hello\"); }, 1000)");
```

It fails with error: "ReferenceError: setInterval is not defined".

Or engines can execute only pure javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V8 Engine can execute only pure javascript. But you mimic the same, by registering setTimeout method in the engine, when you get the call for this function, you can schedule. like following. But you have to use
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()

```
private var setTimeOutCallback: JavaCallback = JavaCallback { _, v8Array ->
    val v8Function = v8Array.getObject(0) as V8Function
    val time = v8Array.getInteger(1).toLong()
    val taskId = Random.nextInt(1000, 9999)
    val task = v8Executor.schedule({
        v8Function.call(runtime, null)
    }, time, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    taskId
}
```

Comment: What is the v8Executor. Should and how can I set the v8Executor to the v8Runtime?

Comment: Here v8Executor is Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
you have to create runtime inside executor.submit
then call all js call is executor.submit or exector.schedule